# Can i install market place in windows 6.1?

Tags: store

Is it possible for me to have market place installed in my windows mobile. Where can i get the  cab file for it?

Comment: Windows Mobile 6.1 is a totally different operating system. Everything written for Windows Phone 7 and higher won't work on it. Besides, this page is dedicated to Windows Phone and not Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 6):

The MarketPlace for Windows Mobile 6.x was retired a few years ago. Even if you had a copy of the cab file, it wouldn't work as desired, as the store server has been closed down.